# Como fazer um `Uint8Array` se tornar um `BigInt` no JS?

Tags: javascript, golang, webassembly

Eu estou usando uma outra linguagem, em WebAssembly, e preciso criar um `BigInt` utilizando um `Uint8Array`.

---

No `Golang`, os `big.Int` são representados da seguinte forma:

```
type Int struct {
    neg bool // sign
    abs nat  // absolute value of the integer
}
type nat []Word
type Word uint
```

Portanto, eu posso ler a informações do `abs` (que é o `[]byte`) no JS utilizando:

```
const _encPtr = go.mem.getUint32(sp + 8 + 8, true) + go.mem.getInt32(sp + 8 + 8 + 4, true) * 4294967296;
const _encLen = go.mem.getUint32(sp + 8 + 8 + 8, true) + go.mem.getInt32(sp + 8 + 8 + 8 + 4, true) * 4294967296;
const enc = new Uint8Array(go._inst.exports.mem.buffer, _encPtr, _encLen)
```

**As duvidas é:**

Assumindo que o `const enc` terá o `abs` do Golang. Como faço para isso se tornar este array um `BigInt`?

Como posso fazer um `BigInt(new Uint8Array(10))` ou, nesse caso, `BigInt(enc)`?

Na documentação do Mozilla, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt, não há nenhum exemplo. É necessário converter isto para HEX, então do HEX ir para BigInt? Não tem como não fazer essa conversão?

---

Uma das alternativas que pensei, foi em converter o BigInt pra String (ainda no Go) e passar como string pro JS. Mas isto é inviável, porque além de alocar mais memoria, irá utilizar o TextEncoder do JS (pra converter o UTF8 da string do Go para um String do JS), que é muito lento no Chrome.

Comment: Num teste rápido aqui, parece que passar um literal gigante ou expressão funciona (eu esperava que não funcionasse). Não sei se ajuda. `const big = BigInt( Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER * 2 )`. Um artigo que também pode ajudar: https://coolaj86.com/articles/convert-js-bigints-to-typedarrays/.

Comment: @bfavaretto, não sei se isso tem garantia de sempre funcionar, afinal o cálculo ainda está sendo operado no tipo `number` (que não é arbitrário), e não `bigint`. Sobre a pergunta, o WebAssembly já tem uma boa integração com BigInts? Talvez ajude: https://v8.dev/features/wasm-bigint

Comment: Pois é, @LuizFelipe também não confio, como eu disse nem esperava que funcionasse.

Comment: @LuizFelipe acredito que o BigInt do WASM, que este artigo se refere, é ao i64 (int64), já que o JS utiliza int53/float64. O ABI do Go apenas passa o stack-pointer (no caso do meu código o `sp`), no meu caso para ler o `int64` eu crio dois Uint32 e somo (como no código acima, para pegar o pointeiro e o tamanho). _Considerando que o BigInt tem tamanho variável, acho que não tem como passar  um `i1024`, por exemplo, e isso iria exigir mudar o ABI do Go <-> JS._

Comment: @bfavaretto você sugeria então converter cada uint8 pra `BigInt` e então soma-los? Tipo, `n := BigInt(0); for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {  b += array[i] }`? Ou até, criando `Uint32Array` ao invés de `Uint8Array`.

Comment: Prefiro não sugerir nada, pois não sei o bastante sobre BigInt nem sobre typed arrays. Meus comentários foram mais para compartilhar o que vi ao dar uma olhada no tema a partir da sua pergunta. No link do meu primeiro comentário, tem uma seção sobre BigInt64Arrays que me pareceu promissor (numa leitura superficial, entendi que ele dá um caminho para converter esse tipo específico de array para BigInt).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aparentemente não há como usar `BigInt(new Uint8Array(10))` ou nada equivalente.

---

A solução foi então utilizar um loop (assume `data` como um `Uint8Array`, em Big-Endian):

```
function ArrayToBigInt(data) {
    let length = BigInt(data.length)-1n
    let result = BigInt(0)

    for (let i = BigInt(0); i <= length; i++) {
        result += BigInt(data[i]) * (2n << (((length-i) * 8n)-1n))
    }
    return result
}
```

A ideia é simples, para cada `Uint8` multiplicamos por um "offset", nesse caso `2^0` depois `2^8-1` depois `2^16-1` e assim por diante. *Talvez há como "otimizar" essa multiplicação/shift.*

A função funciona se os bytes são Big-Endian, senão use `i` ao invés de `length-i`. É possível usar a mesma lógica para o `Uint32Array` (int32) e `BigInt64Array` (int64), deve apenas ajustar o `8n` para o offset de `32n` ou `64n`.

---

Considerando que estou usando Golang, e ele é um `[]uint` e que o `uint` do WebAssembly, no Go, tem sempre 8 bytes (independente da arquitetura do CPU/OS), temos duas soluções e utilize Little-Endian, temos duas opções:

- Usar `Uint8Array` (codigo acima) com um tamanho de `length * 8`.
- Usar `Uint32Array` com `(2n << (((i) * 32n)-1n))` e tamanho de `length * 2`.
- Usar `BigInt64Array` com `(2n << (((i) * 64n)-1n))`.

Como o primeiro caso é igual ao de cima. O `BigInt64Array` não é suportado no iOS 14 (e inferior) e isto atualmente é relavante. Então, sobra a segunda opção, que estou utilizando no momento.

Considerando o seguinte código em Golang:

- Golang:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "math/big"
)

func main() {
    i := big.NewInt(math.MaxInt64)
    i = big.NewInt(0).Add(i, big.NewInt(math.MaxInt64))
    i = big.NewInt(0).Mul(i, big.NewInt(-43))
    
    fmt.Println("go", i)
    printJSBigInt(i)
}

func printJSBigInt(n *big.Int)
```

- Assembly:

```
#include "textflag.h"

TEXT printJSBigInt(SB), NOSPLIT, $0
  CallImport
  RET
```

- Javascript:

```
"main.printJSBigInt": (sp) => {
    const _bigIntPtr = go.mem.getUint32(sp + 8, true) + go.mem.getInt32(sp + 8 + 4, true) * 4294967296;

    const _negBool = go.mem.getUint32( _bigIntPtr, true) !== 0
    const _absPtr = go.mem.getUint32( _bigIntPtr + 8, true) + go.mem.getInt32( _bigIntPtr + 8 + 4, true) * 4294967296;
    const _absLength = go.mem.getUint32( _bigIntPtr + 8 + 8, true) + go.mem.getInt32( _bigIntPtr + 8 + 8 + 4, true) * 4294967296;

    const data = new Uint32Array(go._inst.exports.mem.buffer, _absPtr, _absLength * 2)

    let length = BigInt(data.length)-1n
    let result = BigInt(0)
    for (let i = BigInt(0); i <= length; i++) {
        result += BigInt(data[i]) * (2n << (((i) * 32n)-1n))
    }

    if (_negBool) {
        result *= -1n
    }

    console.log("js", result)
},
```

- Resultado:

> go -793209995169510719402
> js -793209995169510719402n